# Increase Github API limit

Tags: github, github-api

I have a PHP application that uses the Github API to check if the local system of the user is up to date with the lastest version on Github.

By default you can only query the API 60 times per hour. But i can increase this when i authenticate first. But, you can also increase the rate limit without authenticating. Which is what i want.

The example that i found says i only have to call this URL through `CUrl`:

```
https://api.github.com/users/whatever?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Not sure if this will work, also no idea what they mean with ***whatever*** in the URL.

In anyway this should do trick for increasing the rate limit. But they also say the following:

> This method should only be used **for server-to-server calls**. You should
>   **never share your client secret with anyone** or include it in
>   client-side browser code.

Since my application is an "open source" PHP application, then that basically means i'm going to share my secret key with others who use my application...

Is there any other way to increase the rate limit, without worrying that i'm sharing sensitive data with others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to contact GitHub support to have your ratelimit increased, contrary to what spuder claims. They'll raise it for you.

As for not sharing your `client_id` or `client_secret`, spuder has the right answer there. Use an environment variable in your production system and get that and set the secret/id pair from there. Alternatively, use a configuration file that will be added to `.gitignore` so you never accidentally commit it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not set the client secret as a variable, and purposely put a fake client secret in your code. That will prevent anyone who pulls your code from accidentally or maliciously using your key. To actually use the program, the end user will have to change the key variable.

The number of API requests per hour can not be increased {Correction: unless you contact github}